# Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [System.HttpRequest].setboby(String)

Tags: callout

I'm trying to compile a class that sends an httprequest POST to an external web service and I'm getting an error `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [System.HttpRequest].setboby(String)

Here's my code

```
global class CSTnoteposter {
global static void beginnote(){
notewriter();
}
@future(callout=true)
static void notewriter(){
Step_Instance__c step = [select Id, JSONblockforupload__c, Vault_Key__c, OwnerId from Step_Instance__c where Step_Instance__c.Vault_Key__c != null AND Step_Instance__c.JSONblocksent__c = false];
Id StepID = step.Id;
string ROwner = string.valueof(step.OwnerId);
string Vault_Key = step.Vault_Key__c; 
string JSONblock = step.JSONblockforupload__c;

User RecOwner = [select Id, X_Auth_token__c from User where Id =: Id.valueof(ROwner)];
string XAuth = RecOwner.X_Auth_token__c;
http http1 = new http();
httprequest req = new httprequest();
httpresponse res = new httpresponse();

req.setmethod('POST');
string EndURL ='';
EndURL += 'https://web210.ntree.com/twig-cstc3/v1/vault/'+Vault_Key;
EndURL += '/notes';
req.setendpoint(EndURL);
req.setheader('Content-Type', 'application/json,charset=UTF-8');
req.setheader('accept', 'application/json');
req.setheader('Authorization', XAuth);
req.setboby(JSONblock);
res = http1.send(req);
```

I've checked the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_System_HttpRequest_setBody) and this looks right. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: The method name is setbody() not setboby()

Comment: I was going to edit the question to correct the typo, but the typo is the actual problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message clearly mentions the method doesn't exist and it means some typo error in method name or parameters or the method.

The method name is setbody() not setboby().

Adding this as an answer so you can accept it and question will be counted as closed.